# Blazor - Binding to a collection of objects

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor preview v9

What is required to bind an `EditForm` to a collection of objects?  When I setup my `EditForm` to a collection of objects, exposing and binding their `bool` property, when you click the checkbox they are immediately un-checked.

```
@page "/sompage"

<EditForm Model="MyModel">
    @foreach(var item in MyModel.Items)
    {
        <label>
        <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="item.BoolProperty" />
        @item.Text</label>
    }
</EditForm>

@code
{
    public class SomeModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SomeItem> Items { get;set; } = new List<SomeItem>();
    }
    public class SomeItem
    {
        public string Text { get;set; }
        public bool BoolProperty { get;set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution, much like ASP.NET binding, is to expose mutable collections.  As I had originally exposed the `Items` as `IEnumerable<SomeItem>` the binding magic of Blazor can not update the target collection.

Changing `Items` `List<SomeItem>` does this trick.